# TreeView sorting in GTK# produces incorrect result

Tags: gtk#

We have a large C# application using the GTK# bindings. Recently we became aware of a very strange bug: When the user clicks on a column to sort it, it doesn't sort correctly. To be specific, GTK appears to be ignoring all punctuation (including whitespace) and sorting only on alphabetic characters.

Does anybody have any idea why on Earth it would do something like that?

We're not doing anything fancy with custom sorting or anything like that. I'm really puzzled as to why it doesn't just sort the strings in ASCII order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We eventually solved this by adding a custom sorting function that just does a normal ASCII comparison.

I'm still baffled as to why this doesn't happen by default in the first place... so if anybody knows, write your answer here.